# Create an column of empty array with pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I would like to add to an existing dataframe a column containing empty array/list like the following:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `[ ]` |
| 2 | `[ ]` |
| 3 | `[ ]` |

To be filled later on.

I tried the following:

```
df = df.withColumn("col2", F.array(None))
```

or by creating an empty column first:

```
df= df.withColumn("empty_col", F.lit(None).cast(T.StringType()))
df= df.withColumn("col2", F.array(F.col("empty_col")))
```

but the latest give an array with a null string in it, not an empty string

**Edit:**

It worked with:

```
df = df.withColumn("col2", F.array().cast("array<string>"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `None` in your first approach, so

```py
df = df.withColumn("col2", F.array())
```

Comment: it raise an error: 
Parquet data source does not support array<null> data type.;

But with: 
df = df.withColumn("col2", F.array().cast("array<string>"))

It worked ! thanks